# Facebook get user about page information using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, userinfo

Is there any way to get information in user About page using graph API?

For instance, we can get the user Work and education by going here

> http://www.facebook.com/van.trankhanh.1/about

But there is no information about Work and education if we use this

> https://graph.facebook.com/van.trankhanh.1?access_token=AAAEaY81Vw24BAB96Yf2VNWMm8GdjMctjxGQj3ycrtoi7RhMn4SCOOVGcgtaZCuyHbP3nNyKulleaQ440IvQKHWlub2TZC6TrIWrLGIYgZDZD

Comment: Have you consulted the Developer Docs [reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)?

Comment: Yes, I have read them but confuse. Why we can freely view more information of many users by going directly to http://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/about, but just basic information by using api with one access token.